# Why is there the error?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have one problem at the following code:

```
public Menu menu;
public TextView tv;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView textv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.mysql);
    tv = textv;
    Connect();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.login:
            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(loginIntent, LOGIN_REQUEST);
            return true;
        case R.id.register:

            return true;
        default:    
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}   
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
}

protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == LOGIN_REQUEST){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

    private class Connect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = "";

            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
                System.out.println("Database connection success"); 

                String result = "Database connection success\n";
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from login");
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

                while(rs.next()) {
                    result += rsmd.getColumnName(1) + ": " + rs.getInt(1) + "\n";
                    result += rsmd.getColumnName(2) + ": " + rs.getString(2) + "\n";
                    result += rsmd.getColumnName(3) + ": " + rs.getString(3) + "\n";
                }
                tv.setText(result);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                tv.setText(e.toString());
            }
            return response;   


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            tv.setText(result);
        }
    }

    public void Connect() {
        Connect task = new Connect();
        task.execute();

    }
```

on line 80, thats the line:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
```

but i don't know why.
I don't forget the Internetpermissions
I think there is something wrong with the connector library.

Comment: Have you initialized properly `url`, `user` and `pass`?

Comment: You don't want to call setText() inside doInBackground, instead publish progress and do it from onProgressUpdate. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: yeah i initialized url user pass and these things but i let them out cause this data are secret ^^

Comment: @Juan-devtopia.coop - Actually, onPublishProgress isn't needed as the poster is already calling setText in onPostExecute, exactly where this should be happening given the posted code. But the tv.setText in the Exception block should definitely not be there.